# How to change a value stored in an address in x86?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a register whose content is an address. Now I want to change the value stored in that address, how can I do this in x86 assembly?

For example

mov $5, %r10

//r10 contains an address addr, location addr stores a value, now I want to set this value to be 5.

Comment: Using what assembler syntax?

Comment: "change a value stored ***in*** an address" doesn't make any sense. Are you trying to change the value in the register? Or are you trying to change the vale stored *in* memory *at* a particular address?

Answer (score 4):

Since this appears to be AT&T syntax,

```
movb $5,(%r10)
```

to store a byte. The assembler won't be able to infer the size of $5, so you can't use `mov` but have to specify `movb` directly (or `movl` etc. if you mean something other than a byte).